# Activate wifi with password

Tags: wireless, password

is it somehow possible to set a password so that you can't turn on wifi?

thanks in advance
Christian

Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible to set a password to specifically protect wifi activation.
But you can deactivate the wlan interface with `[sudo] ifdown wlan0`.
To activate the interface again with `[sudo] ifup wlan0` root privileges are required, so the user has to know the root password.

Comment: thanks for you answer
sadly this doesn't help. I wanted to use my netbook for my exams but no communicating devices are allowed. I hope if I could let someone deactivate my wifi with a password I may be able to use it. ;)

Comment: That is not possible unfortunately. And even if it was, I doubt that you would be allowed to use your notebook anyway.

Comment: @user297716 - even it is extremely unlikely that they would let you use it, even if you wiped it and re-installed it. You could still have notes on it etc, and they can't allow anyone a chance of cheating - they even do [posters](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/plymouth-university-to-take-down-anticheating-posters-after-they-were-found-to-be-helping-students-cheat-9321670.html?origin=internalSearch) about it :D

Comment: =) we are allowed to use all our notes..therefore this wouldn't be a problem.
But as blocking wlan activation isn't possible this doesn't matter.
Thanks